# How could java sending data to 7segment display directly

Tags: java, serial-port, embedded

I'm new to embedded systems,
could i send data from java application on my pc to serial 7 segment display direct via serial port or i have to use micro-controller in between

Comment: What kind of display is it? If it's the usual "bare bones" type with just 7 LEDs and nothing else, then yes you will need a micro-controller in between.

Comment: i want to use this type https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11442

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"TTL serial communication" *probably* means the same protocol used by a PC serial port, but at a different voltage.

You will be able to connect it to a serial port if you use a level shifter in between to convert the voltages. Search for "MAX232" chips, which are designed to do exactly this. There will be a bit of wiring involved. For more help with this part, try https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

On the software side, I don't know if Java has a way to access serial ports. There is probably a 3rd-party library to do this, but C might be better-suited anyway.